# Add password to keytool command

Tags: batch-file, keytool

I've made a .bat file to get the SHA1 of my Android app so I don't need to type the command each time

`keytool -list -v -keystore "Path/To/My/Key.jks"`

When I run the bat file I get asked for the password. Is it possible to either put the password in the command e.g. something like `--password MyPassword`, or in the .bat file wait for the Enter your password line, and then send the password? I don't have any experience really with .bat files so I don't know if that's possible to do or not.

I looked at the --help for keytool and the only password flags I could see were for changing the password, not specifying it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `keytool` that ships with the Oracle JDK allows you to specify it on the command line with `-storepass`, you were doing `keytool -help` instead of `keytool -list -help`. (I suppose the Android version is the same.)

```
C:\>keytool.exe -list -help
keytool -list [OPTION]...

Lists entries in a keystore

Options:

 -rfc                            output in RFC style
 -alias <alias>                  alias name of the entry to process
 -keystore <keystore>            keystore name
 -storepass <arg>                keystore password
 -storetype <storetype>          keystore type
 -providername <providername>    provider name
 -providerclass <providerclass>  provider class name
 -providerarg <arg>              provider argument
 -providerpath <pathlist>        provider classpath
 -v                              verbose output
 -protected                      password through protected mechanism

Use "keytool -help" for all available commands
```

Comment: I tested, the `-storepass` option is also present in the `keytool` found in `openjdk`

Answer (score 19):

Specify the keystore password using the `-storepass` option:

```
keytool <commands and options> -storepass changeit
```

`changeit` being the default keystore password, but use whatever.

For example, to add a certificate using the default password:

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias mycert -file mycert.cer -keystore .../lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Answer (score 4):

As @sastorsl said, if you are worried about putting your password in clear text in your command or script (and you should), you should put your password in a secure file (with 0400 permissions, in Linux) or in an environment variable.

Now `keytool` does have a similar construct to `openssl`'s `file:<filename>`, if your password is in a file:

```
keytool <commands and options> -storepass:file <pass_file>
```

If your password is in an environment variable:

```
keytool <commands and options> -storepass:env <pass_var>
```

Disclaimer: I have tested the `-storepass:file` option in Bash (not in Windows), but the documentation does not seem to have any difference according to the OS.

From the [Oracle keytool doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/keytool.html):

> **`-storepass [:env | :file ] argument`**
>
> The password that is used to protect the integrity of the keystore.
>
> If the modifier `env` or `file` isn’t specified, then the password has the `value` argument, which must contain at least six characters. Otherwise, the password is retrieved as follows:
>
> `env`: Retrieve the password from the environment variable named `argument`.
>
> `file`: Retrieve the password from the file named argument.
>
> Note: All other options that require passwords, such as `-keypass`, `-srckeypass`, `-destkeypass`, `-srcstorepass`, and `-deststorepass`, accept the `env` and `file` modifiers. Remember to separate the password option and the modifier with a colon (:).

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about storing your password in a script, and for it to turn up in your command line history - which you should be, store the password in a separate file instead, secure it, and reference it.

NB! This is Linux / ***bash*** specific, and OP seems to be on windows, but I hope this can help somebody else.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "Path/To/My/Key.jks" -storepass $(cat < <(cat bin/.pw))
```

If only `keytool` would have the `file:<filename>` construct which the `openssl` client has.